# SSRS Chart Y-Axis split in three scales

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, scale, yaxis

After searching for a week, I finally decided to put my question here. My aim is to create a ssrs chart Y-Axis which contains three different scales like in the following screenshot:

[image]

Is this possible? I have a Datasource with different Series Groups, and for each of them I want a different scale in the chart. At the moment it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: A single chart can only have two X axes. You can assign a series to the secondary axis and that will be independant but what you are trying to achieve with three is not possible in a single chart. Check here for more info and look in the section regarding using a secondary Axis. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/multiple-series-on-a-chart-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Okay, Thanks for that information. Is it also possible to make for every Series Group a Chart in a Chart Area?

Comment: @AlanSchofield or is it possible to do it via expression

Comment: I "think" the only way to do that would be to transform your data so each series is in a separate column. I can't test anything right now, it might be possible to use an expression in the series values to pull out each series and then get rid of your series groups.

Comment: Oh and II obviously meant to say Y axis in my earlier comment but it's too late to edit it.

Comment: @AlanSchofield any tips for a solution? I have tried it like you meant but didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with the same Struggle, I made it with chart areas. In the series of the chart i made three series for every diffrent value.